# Everyone's or every one's?

Tags: word-choice

I've always written 'everyone's' but when I was writing a post for my blog the Spell Check came up with 'every one's"
Which one is it?

Comment: Mom just checked all the apples in her "winter storage" box, but ***every one's*** gone mouldy. So ***everyone's*** disappointed, because we all love [Mom’s Apple Pie](http://www.yelp.co.uk/biz/moms-apple-pie-occoquan)

Answer (score 2):

They have two different meanings.

**everyone** means *'all the people there'* and refers only to people

**every one** means *'every single one'*, *'each one'* and can also refer to non-people (as in @FumbleFingers' apple example)